# Objective C - cannot open my app by Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm new to iOS development. Today I try to embed the firebase Dynamic Link in my App to generate links to share. I try to implement it as the tutorial video, but after I set the Associated Domains in Capabilities and URL type in Info. I cannot open the app by tap URL like the demo in the video. The setting is like this: [image]

[image]

and when I open https://q326v.app.goo.gl/apple-app-site-association, the result also looks fine.
[image]
[image]

Anyone have the idea what the problem is? Thanks very much!

Comment: Ensure that your app's App Store ID and your App ID prefix is specified in your app's settings.

Comment: my app hasn't been in the apple store yet, so it does not have an App Store ID. Is that essential?

Comment: firebase says it's essential https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's typo in Firebase doc, App Store ID not essential for dynamic links to works. App Prefix ID is essential and you seems to have done this.

Looking on your apple-app-site-association and your Xcode screenshot, you are all set. The problem you facing now is related to iOS Universal Links. Try long tap on your link while App is installed, you should see option "Open in ". Ensure you uninstalled and then re-installed the App, ensure you did not disabled Universal Links for your App, check StackOverflow for common issues related to Universal Links.